# CloudFormation template error Fn::Sub intrinsic functions don't specify expected arguments

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation

Portion of Cloudformation template dealing with Lambda function below. Expectation is that I can use the Sub function to add in the SNS Topic provided by the user during stack creation.

```
"GetApiKeyValueLambdaFunction": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
    "Properties": {
      "Code": {
        "ZipFile": {"Fn::Sub":[
            {
                "Fn::Join": ["\n", [
                  "import json",
                  "import boto3",
                  "client = boto3.client('apigateway')",
                  "sns_client = boto3.client('sns')",
                  "def lambda_handler(event, context):",
                  "    response = client.get_api_key(",
                  "        apiKey=event['apiKeyId'],",
                  "        includeValue=True",
                  "    )",
                  "    response_message = {'key_name' : response['name'], 'key_value' : response['value']}",
                  "    sns_client.publish(",
                  "        TargetArn='/${__snstopic__}',",
                  "        Message=json.dumps({'default': json.dumps(response_message,indent=1)}),",
                  "        MessageStructure='json'",
                  "    )",
                  "    return {",
                  "        'statusCode': 200,",
                  "        'body': response['value']}"
                          ]   ] 
                      },
                {
                    "__snstopic__":{"Ref" : "SnsOutputTopic"}
                }
                ]}
      },
      "Handler": "index.lambda_handler",
      "Runtime": "python3.6",
      "Timeout": 30,
      "Role": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "CustomLambdaExecutionRole", "Arn"
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

However template validation fails with the following error:

> 4/15/2019, 1:20:22 PM - Template contains errors.: Template error:
>   One or more Fn::Sub intrinsic functions don't specify expected
>   arguments. Specify a string as first argument, and an optional second
>   argument to specify a mapping of values to replace in the string

I am wondering if there's a certain order for how to use Fn Sub and Fn Join together? But I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: don't need to use sub and join together, I not understood the part  {
                    "__snstopic__":{"Ref" : "SnsOutputTopic"}
                }

Comment: I want the user to input an SNS topic ARN when they start the stack creation. I want that ARN to form part of the python code for the lambda function shown above. So I need Fn::Join for the python code, and Fn::Sub to add in the SNS Topic. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think you can put values directly in a string with ${} and pass it to Sub. I added a code snippet in the answer section. check it out

Answer (score 0):

No need to use sub and join together. here is a code snippet (I just converted it to yaml)

```
GetApiKeyValueLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    Code:
      ZipFile:
        !Sub |
          import json, boto3
          client = boto3.client('apigateway')
          sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            response = client.get_api_key(apiKey=event['apiKeyId'], includeValue=True)
            response_message = {'key_name' : response['name'], 'key_value': response['value']}
            sns_client.publish( TargetArn='${SnsOutputTopic}', Message=json.dumps({'default': json.dumps(response_message,indent=1)}), MessageStructure='json')
            return { 'statusCode': 200, 'body': response['value'] }
    Handler: index.lambda_handler
    Runtime: python3.6
    Timeout: 30
    Role:
      Fn::GetAtt:
      - CustomLambdaExecutionRole
      - Arn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a bash script within your metadata and come across this error, options 1 and 2 in my example code are valid but option 3 is not because **"- |"** tells the sub intrinsic function to expect another **"- |"** as shown in option 1, that should provide mapping of values (e.g ***- {A mapping of some sort}***) to replace strings inside ***{blablabla}***. When the second mapping is not found, the error is thrown.

```
Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
   files:
   ##### use
    '/dir/subdir':
      content: !Sub
        - |
          {blablabla}
        - {A mapping of some sort}
    ###### or 

    '/dir2/subdir2':
      content: !Sub |
          {blablabla}

    ##### But don't mix like so

    '/dir3/subdir3':
      content: !Sub
        - |
          {blablabla}
```